# How can I convert a case class to a Map (in Scala.js)

Tags: scala, scala.js

How can I convert a `case class` to a `Map` where the fields of the `case class` become the keys?

For example:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val p = Person("dude", 89)
val map = p.toMap // <-- ???
```

so that `map` equals the following map:

```
Map("name" -> "dude", "age" -> 89)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically achieved with reflection or macros, since it involves looking up the names of Scala fields, which does not exist at runtime. In Scala.js, you're restricted to macros, since runtime reflection does not exist.

There are serialization libraries that do this transformation automatically with macros. Here are a couple candidates, which work in Scala.js:

- [uPickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle)
- [Prickle](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle)
- ([Scala.js pickling](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-pickling) - probably not adapted to you if you need clean maps)

Comment: thanks for answer , i tired upickle before ,it has some issues with Map ,https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle/issues/39 , will wait for it!.

Comment: The issue you mention is about serializing Maps [to JSON], not about serializing [case classes] *to* maps.

Comment: could pleas tell me the exact API name ,from the docs i see read readJS,write,writeJs , so i trie like this , read[Map[String,Any]](write[Person](Person("dude",89)))

Comment: `write` should give you a JSON object (given the appropriate implicit), which you can then  cast to a `js.Dictionary` and then convert to map: `write(...).asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[Any]].toMap`

Comment: thank you ,it worked JSON.parse(write[Person](Person("dude",34))).asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[Any]].toMap

Comment: Is there a way to go directly from the case class to a JSON object, rather than having to write to a string first and then having to use JSON.parse ?